# convert PDF to byte

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service which stores documents(PDF files) uploaded by a user to a file server.Now,I want to convert these PDF files to bytes so an iOS client can download them on iPad.I do not want to store the PDFs as BLOB in SQL,just convert into bytes and send them to iPad. Any links/sample code to achieve this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply read the PDF file into a byte array:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathToFile);
```

Comment: part of the question involves the pdf file streaming over wcf

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like below:

```
public byte[] ReadPDF(string filePath)
        {
            byte[] buffer;
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            try
            {
                int length = (int)fileStream.Length;  // get file length
                buffer = new byte[length];            // create buffer
                int count;                            // actual number of bytes read
                int sum = 0;                          // total number of bytes read

                // read until Read method returns 0 (end of the stream has been reached)
                while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
                    sum += count;  // sum is a buffer offset for next reading
            }
            finally
            {
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            return buffer;
        }
```

Comment: There are some issues with this code. The `while` loop is not necessary because you read all bytes from the stream in the first read. Also, you can use an `using` statement instead of a `try/finally` block. All in all M4N's answer is doing the same in a much simpler way.

Comment: yes M4N's answer is much simpler but mine is 2nd solution to the problem.